# Broken category styling

Tags: categories, css

My category url at https://thienduongduhoc.com/fun-facts somehow the styling is broken and there only white screen and blue fonts. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: All looking fine at my end. Did you resolved the issue? If yes, please share the solution. I presume it was due to WP upgrade.

Comment: @hilaryk can you provide an image of how it's suppose to look

Comment: @frenchyblack : please have a look of my screenshot. Help me out

Comment: what browser are you using cause when me and @Jiten Gaikwad looked at it it seems fine but your screenshot shows otherwise

Comment: @frenchyblack Im using Chrome. But on my phone , I use Safari to click on that categories and it still has problem shown as screenshot

Comment: @hilaryk it looks fine on browser in my phone too. can you tried it after clearing your cache on browser?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is how it looks like at my end. I have checked it in chrome, mozilla and IE as well. It look fine in all browsers.

Comment: I wish I can say the same for my try but unfortunately the problem is still on my side. Im real hopeless now

Comment: @hilaryk it looks fine on browser in my phone too. can you try it after clearing your cache on browser? Try to access the site from incognito window.

Comment: I just surf on incognito mode and still nothing. Im thinking its due to my new theme update or the fact I deleted the plugin Hide my wp but its still has cache in cpanel or something.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is the img from my screenshot]

I still can't resolve the issue. I'm so troubled right now....